# Google BigQuery - Is there a way to calculate continously a cell based on sum of below row?

Tags: excel, google-bigquery

I have a dataset like this:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Oz3.png)

where "x"s are known numbers, "y"s are known and are sum of "x"s in the same row.

I want to calculate all the empty cells from B2 to H7.

The logics are:

- "y" is the sum of same row "x"s.
- "x" is calculated by multiplying "y" of previous row with the coresponding value of "x" in "p" (meaning percentage) columns.

E.g: cell `C7 = B8*I7`.
Then `B7 = SUM(C7:H7)`. Then `D6 = B7*J6`
`C6 = B7*I6`.
Then `B6 = SUM(C6:H6)`
So on and so forth.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

I want to calculate all the empty cells in B2:H7. Or only the empty "y"s in B2:B7 is fine.